# Can't get text out of Webelement using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

I'm using Python 3.11.5, and I want to extract text from a Webelement with selenium.

I use Chromedriver as a driver, and I want to find an element By.CLASS_NAME

**Here is my code**

[image]

**What happens ?**

- When I print (element), it gives me a Webdriver element, which I can't read.
- When I print (element.text), it gives me an error :

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001DDFE4F0690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée')': /session/0109eeaf781d2f899ee82e0fd10eac19/execute/sync

**What have I tried ?**

- After using driver.get(url), I already tried to apply time.sleep(10)
- I checked my versions of Chrome + Chromedriver
- I disabled my proxy

**Do you have any idea about what the problem is ?**

Comment: Have you tried moving `print element.text` to before the `driver.quit` statement? The error message suggests that a connection via the driver is necessary to read the element properties.

Comment: @KatePaulk I'm gonna try this. Data comes in and out at random timings on the website I'm scraping so I can't tell you when I'll know, but I'll let you know.
Thanks for the advice !